# Shortest Path with multiple "must have" Nodes in Graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I do have an Graph (~250 Nodes). To connect to an Node I have to buy it with Points ->weighted Graph. 
There are Nodes which are always taken ("claimed Nodes") and from those I can begin to connect to other Nodes. Furthermore I do have an limited amount of Points. All Nodes can be connected together.

What way is there to get an Graph where all must have Nodes are connected together, with the least Points? If possible with a given maximum Points.

2nd) Is there an way that it´s not necessary an completely connected Graph? e.g.: One Node which is a "must have Node" is directly connected to an "claimed Node", so the cheapest Way to get it would be just get the must have Node and not connect it with the remaining Graph.

**EDIT** (regarding the first three questions): I do have to buy the Node itself, not the Connection. So, I do not count the Travel Distance but the Node cost. e.g.: If I have an Graph from A to B, B to C and A to C and B is an "must have Node" I can "travel" from A to B then from B to A and from A to C (if it´s shorter than B to C) because there is no additional cost from B to A because B is already claimed.

I came up with this Algorithm:
I do make an Table with all the "must have Nodes" and begin form one of those. I use either an Breath First Search or an  Depth First Search (what would be better?) and let it branch as long as it not find an "must have Node" and will - if needed - update the shortest Distance. When it find an "must have Node" it ends this Branch and stores it´s Path. The Distance will be registered in the Table. It will run as long as it find´s no "must have Node". When it´s done I will go ahead in the Table and take the next "must have Node", do the same and built the table.
When I am done with all the Nodes I will run an Minimum Spanning Tree Algorithm over the Table and should get my optimal Graph.

Anyone does see an Problem with this one?

Comment: What algorithms have you discovered and tried?

Comment: I do not really understand the description of this problem ... but I GUESS it's related to Minimun Spanning Trees, for which fast algorithms exist.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you're trying to find a *path*.

Comment: "To connect to an Node I have to buy it with Points", do you have to buy the connection (the edge) or the node?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem corresponds to [Node Weighted Steiner Tree](http://theory.cs.uni-bonn.de/info5/steinerkompendium/node15.html).

(tinLoaf's link is to the edge-weighted version, which is very-much the default for Steiner Tree.)

Node Weighted Steiner Tree ​ -> ​ your problem ​ ​ :

If S is empty then the empty subgraph is a solution, else let any one element of S be

the unique claimed Node and let the "must have" Nodes be the other elements of S.

your problem ​ -> ​ Node Weighted Steiner Tree ​ ​ :

If you mean the claimed Nodes also need to be connected to each other, then there's no difference between those and the must-have nodes, so let S be the union of [the set of claimed Nodes]

with [the set of must-have Nodes]. ​ If you mean that each must-have Node just needs to be connected to at least one claimed Node, then [collapse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_contraction#Vertex_identification) the claimed Nodes into each other

and let S be the union of {resulting_node} with [the set of "must have" Nodes].

Note that [the uni-bonn link](http://theory.cs.uni-bonn.de/info5/steinerkompendium/node15.html) (from the beginning of this answer)

has at least one wrong result about approximation -

The actual main positive result is ​ ​ ​ "[The node weighted Steiner tree problem can](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0890540198927547/1-s2.0-S0890540198927547-main.pdf?_tid=c79683c0-526e-11e6-8a1e-00000aab0f01&acdnat=1469454823_f1a3c263305dc7241a7450d8958ff3b7#page=11)

[be approximated to a factor of ​ 1.35 (1+epsilon') ln k ​ for any ​ epsilon' > 0 .](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0890540198927547/1-s2.0-S0890540198927547-main.pdf?_tid=c79683c0-526e-11e6-8a1e-00000aab0f01&acdnat=1469454823_f1a3c263305dc7241a7450d8958ff3b7#page=11)" ​ .
(They left out the ​ 1+epsilon' ​ factor.)

Also, the uni-bonn link's reference for hardness-of-approximation makes no claim on that aspect,

although the result is known - It's at least [as hard to](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.42.3433&rep=rep1&type=pdf#page=4) approximate [as set cover](http://people.csail.mit.edu/dmoshkov/papers/set-cover/set-cover-full.pdf#page=2).

When [parameterized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameterized_complexity) by [number of nodes in solution that are neither claimed nor must-have],

the reduction from set cover still applies, so if that number is small then you're

you're unlikely to do significantly better in the worst case than brute force.

I haven't found anything else applicable applicable from parameterized complexity, although

*edge*-weighted Steiner tree [is known to](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00186-007-0146-0) be [FPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameterized_complexity#FPT) when parameterized by number of terminals.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a Steiner Tree Problem [0], which is NP-hard, but may be solvable for 250 Nodes. I think you can transform it like this:

- Insert a dummy root vertex
- Connect it to every "claimed vertex" via an edge with weight 0 - now all your "claimed vertices" can be connected to the tree (that is to be built) with weight 0
- Solve the "Generalized Steiner Tree Problem" [0] where the set of "must have nodes" forms the set S in the Wikipedia description.

If you can live with approximate solutions: There are some approximations for the steiner tree problem (which the Wikipedia article should mention, too).

[0] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem#Generalization_of_minimum_Steiner_tree